# Using coffeescript with basic Yeoman project.

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs, yeoman

I've used [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) to make a quick project skeleton using the `yo webapp` generator command. In the resulting Gruntfile I see that it's setup to compile CoffeeScript but it seems like its just sticking compiled files in a `tmp` folder.

```
coffee: {
    dist: {
        files: {
           '.tmp/scripts/coffee.js': '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/*.coffee'
        }
    },
},
```

How do these get included in the project during development. I'm not using RequireJS.

The yeoman docs are unclear on how to use coffeescript. They only mention that it gets automatically compiled.

Answer (score 17):

Using yeomen 1.0.0-rc1.4. I use:

```
$ yo angular --coffee
```

The resulting project has controller and app scripts in CoffeeScript.

grunt configuration file remains in js (what is not really a problem).

Running

```
$ grunt test
```

runs tests and all seems fine.

```
$ grunt server
```

is also doing what one expects (build the app, test it, starts server, opens the app in web browser and starts watching for changes, so if I change a coffee script file, it is quickly reflected in the web broser.

Documentation also states, one can use `yo` to add particular pieces like

- angular:controller
- angular:directive
- angular:filter
- angular:route
- angular:service
- angular:decorator
- angular:view

each can be called with a `--coffee` switch and get the script in CoffeeScript, e.g.:

```
yo angular:controller user --coffee
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found an issue in the github repo referencing this problem. https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/12

It offers a temporary solution: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/12#issuecomment-13731929